# jquery dropdown focus

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am trying to set a focus on a dropdown within GridView(gridViewDropDown class) when page loads:

```
if ($('select.gridViewDropDown').length)
{
     alert("Found my dropdown");
        //$('select.gridViewDropDown:first').focus();
     setTimeout(function() { $('select.gridViewDropDown').focus(); }, 10);
}
```

I can see the alert which means that dropdown is found but it never gets a focus. What do I need to change here? I am using IE 6/7.

Comment: where is your code? Is it (a) inside a ready event handler? (b) in the page or in a separate script? (c) does the id of the `<select>` on the client side match the id that you're using in the JavaScript block?

Comment: @Russ Yes, it's inside `document.ready`. Class matches otherwise I would not see `alert`.

Comment: @VictorS - ah, but the alert only indicates that a `<select>` with class gridViewDropDown is found, not necessarily the one in question. What element has focus when the page has loaded? Is it worth looking through the page code to see if there is script automatically inserted into the page to focus that element on page load?

Comment: @Russ Looks like no element has a focus when page loads. I have a code that sets up tab indexes not focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try this approach:

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() { $('select.gridViewDropDown').focus(); }, 50);
});
```

You need to wait until the DOM is ready, it's possible that something else is set to steal focus when the page loads (code that's most likely executing when the DOM's ready as well)  This approach times it to be just slightly after *that* happens.

It also takes advantage of how jQuery works, if no elements are found when this function fires, none will steal focus, so it's safe to just leave in there as-is.

Comment: @Nick, Thanks, should I do it on a master page or a content page or doesn't matter?

Comment: @VictorS - Doesn't matter...it's all rendered to the client as one page, putting it in the master if used on multiple pages, otherwise stick it in the content page.

Comment: @Nick Still doesn't get a focus. Can I send that dropdown "Tab" key?

Comment: @Nick Or, do something like this?`$('select.gridViewDropDown').trigger('focus');`

Comment: @Nick Looks like `$('select.gridViewDropDown').trigger('focus');` works while `$('select.gridViewDropDown').focus();` doesn't, don't know why

Comment: @VictorS - Something else is going on there, not sure what, are there other focus events attached?

Comment: @Nick Think I have an idea but I have to keep that other stuff so I will use `trigger` for now.

Comment: @VictorS - If it works then I see no reason not to leave it using `.trigger()`, I am curious what causes the other handler to interfere though.

Comment: @Nick - Looks like other developers tried to use REQUEST_LASTFOCUS field to restore focus between postbacks.

Comment: @Nick Turns out `focus()` doesn't bubble in IE so that was a problem. Why `trigger` works then I don't know